# Improve map plot resolution

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot an image of a map, using matplotlib. On top of it I'm looking to plot a hiking route using a dataframe of of Longitude/Latitude/Elevation. The image resolution is not good and I'm trying to improve it. However, when I try to add more map tiles it doesn't get any better. I would like it to be of a resolution that looks good when printing a photo. I'd like the works on the map to be clear/sharp. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code that creates the image:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

resolution = 0.03

minLong = -119.5665
maxLong = -119.489072
minLat = 37.725664
maxLat = 37.767836

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

osm_tiles = cimgt.OSM()
ax.set_extent([minLong- resolution, 
               maxLong + resolution,
               minLat - resolution, 
               maxLat + resolution])

ax.add_image(osm_tiles, 13)  # 10 is the zoom level, adjust as needed for more detail

xLat = 37.730172
xLong = -119.557938
ax.scatter(xLong, xLat, color='black',
            marker='x', s=500)

fig.savefig('output_photos/%s_StackExchange_mapPhoto.jpg'%(imgName),dpi=400)
```

[image: matplotlibImage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are using another lib because the looks of **cartopy** arent that good. Ive tried another parameters and changing the font but it didn't worked out

```
import folium
```

Folium is a lib that uses leaflet.js to make maps

Since Folium results are interactive, this library is very useful for dashboard building

```
import time
```

This module provides various functions to manipulate time values.

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

As we are generating a html file we are using **selenium** to take a screenshot of the map

```
import os
```

We are importing the os library to delete the temporary html file we generated

I've raised the resolution too

```
resolution = 0.01

minLong = -119.5665
maxLong = -119.489072
minLat = 37.725664
maxLat = 37.767836
```

Your imgName variable wasnt defined, so i defined it here

```
imgName = 'map'
```

Create a folium map centered at the mean latitude and longitude a follow up with the code comments for the rest of the image generation process

```
m = folium.Map(location=[(minLat + maxLat) / 2, (minLong + maxLong) / 2], zoom_start=14)

#save the interactive map as an HTML file
html_file = 'output_photos/%s_StackExchange_mapPhoto.html' % (imgName)
m.save(html_file)

#initialize the Selenium web driver (assuming ChromeDriver is in your PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#here you should put the path to the folder of the output_photos
myPath = "C:/Users/User/py/"

#open the saved HTML file in the web browser
driver.get(f'file://{myPath}{html_file}')

#wait for a few seconds to ensure the map loads completely (adjust the delay if needed)
time.sleep(5)

#capture a screenshot of the web page
screenshot_file = 'output_photos/%s_StackExchange_mapPhoto.png' % (imgName)
driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_file)

#close the web browser and the web driver
driver.quit()

#delete the HTML file
os.remove(myPath + html_file)

#echo the path to the screenshot file
print(f'Screenshot saved as {screenshot_file}')
```

I hope that helps! Here it generated a very beautiful image!

Happy Coding!

[image: map]